# Reading church name in Gaelic on Marriage Certificate

Tags: palaeography, marriage-records, translation, irish-gaelic

[image: Place of solemnization from Marriage Certificate]

I've just found a certificate online and I'm trying to work out in which church the marriage took place because it is written in Gaelic.

Can you translate it for me?

[image: Scan of whole Marriage Certificate]

Comment: I don't have time to do a proper search, but checking the addresses (Tolka Rd & St. Attracta Road) shows that the church is in Dublin (Gaelic: _Baile Átha Cliath_), which is in the county of Leinster.  The bride lived in the Cabra (Gaelic: _An Chabrach_) district of the city.  Some of the spellings on the certificate seem a bit off.  Hopefully this will help someone identify the specific church.

Answer (score 6):

Building on @sempaiscuba's highly informative comment:

> checking the addresses (Tolka Rd & St. Attracta Road) shows that the church is in Dublin (Gaelic: Baile Átha Cliath), which is in the county of Leinster. The bride lived in the Cabra (Gaelic: An Chabrach) district of the city.

I checked [dublinchurches.com](http://www.dublinchurches.com/churches/start.htm), which lists two current Roman Catholic churches in the Cabra district. These, with Google translations into Irish, are:

1) Christ the King - Críost an Rí
2) Church of the Most Precious Blood - Eaglais na Fola is Lómhara

There's clearly some caution needed here as Google's translation of the second one changes wildly if I vary the capitalisation. But that may not matter.

The central part of the church name at the top of the certificate looks like a good match to "Críost an Rí", so I'd say it's likely that the marriage took place at a Roman Catholic Church of Christ the King, and the [one in Cabra](https://www.christthekingparish.ie/) appears to be the only one of that name in Dublin today, at least.

Answer (score 4):

A minor correction to the foregoing excellent interpretations: Dublin (Baile Atha Cliath) is in the County of Dublin (also Baile Atha Cliath), which is in the PROVINCE (not COUNTY) of Leinster.